# how to receieve json array in codeigneetr 4

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter-4

i am trying to send json stringfy array from ajax to Codeigniter 4 controller. but i am not able to receive array in CodeIgniter controller. I am getting error

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

here is my ajax code

```
let adbtn = document.getElementById("aDDbtn");
adbtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const xhtp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhtp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  var test1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  xhtp.open("POST", window.location.origin + "/crud/test", false);
  xhtp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  let my_json = JSON.stringify(test1);
  xhtp.send(my_json);
});
```

---

and here is my codeigneter function

```
 public function test()
        {
          $n= $this->request->getPost("my_json");
          $array=json_decode($n);
          var_dump($array);
          exit;
        }
```

---

i had javascript array , i converted this to jason stringyfy then tried to decode that but am failed. can anyone please help me ? correct me where am wrong ? i tried to solve bymyself but not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like me for json request

```
 public
    function sendActivateCodeViaSms()
    {$res['data']='soem data';

        return $this->response->setJSON($res)
            ->setStatusCode(ResponseInterface::HTTP_OK, 'get data')
            ->setContentType('application/json');


    }
```